# ¿Pregunta +50 sin respuesta buena?

Tags: discusión, recompensas

Me pasa que ofrecí +50 en una pregunta porque quería ganar la medalla Altruista. Vi que había una pregunta que no tenía suficiente atención y pensé ayudar al que había formulado la pregunta. Pero este parece no tener mucho interés por darnos la solución. Es esta: ([¿Cómo teletransportar un auto?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24260/c%C3%B3mo-teletransportar-un-auto))

¿Cuándo puedo dar los +50? ¿Cuando terminen los días o cuando yo quiera? ¿Y a quién se los doy si el que preguntó ignora a los que responden pues no da el visto bueno a ninguno?

Comment: No he hecho una recompensa sobre la pregunta de otra persona, pero creo que en ese caso eres tú quien elige quién se merece los puntos. De no ser así, entonces por defecto, si no hay una respuesta aceptada, la recompensa se aplica a la respuesta con más votos a favor (aunque creo que solo aplica la mitad de la recompensa).

Comment: Es como dice  @LuiggiMendoza, si no la otorgas manualmente se asigna por la mitad del bonus a la respuesta con más votos. http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Comment: Gracias por vuestras respuestas. ¿La otra mitad del bonus se pierde?

Comment: @MarcLemien Sí. Una recompensa ofrecida no se puede recuperar. Sólo se puede volver a ofrecer una nueva recompensa en caso de que quieras seguir buscando una nueva respuesta.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Como bien dice Luiggi en los comentarios, eres tú quien elige quién se lleva la recompensa. No tiene nada que ver con la persona que elige la respuesta aceptada. **Tú iniciaste una recompensa, tú decides quién se la merece.** Incluso si tu decisión no coincide con la decisión de la persona que pregunta.

Y como indica Alan y se explica en el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), si no eliges ninguna respuesta para darle la recompensa, ésta se asignará automáticamente a la respuesta con la mayor reputación (siempre que tenga al menos 2) que haya sido publicada después de que la ofrecieras, pero sólo recibirá la mitad de su valor.

La otra mitad de la recompensa se perderá... aunque técnicamente ya se había perdido porque a ti te quitaron todos los puntos de la recompensa al iniciarla. No se devuelven para evitar que haya gente que inicie recompensas para luego no otorgarlas y recibir los puntos (o parte de ellos) de vuelta.

Comment: Gracias Álvaro.

Comment: Yo añadiría que `ésta se asignará automáticamente a la respuesta con más votos positivos (siempre que tenga más de 2` **y se haya formulado después de que la recompensa empezara**). Por lo demás, muy buena respuesta :)

Comment: @FranciscoRomero tienes razón. Además, con reputación de 2 ya vale. Nótese la diferencia entre reputación y votos positivos (reputación=positivos-negativos).